# ManyToManyField is not saving in DB

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

I have searched the existing answers on this platform related to this but it isn't helping me. 
I save the Form but it is not saved in the DB.

views.py:

```
def student_list(request, pk) :
course = get_object_or_404(Course, pk=pk)
teacher = Instructor.objects.get(course_name=course)
attendance = Attendance.objects.create(course_name=course, instructor_name=teacher)
if request.method == "POST" :
    form = PostForm(request.POST, instance=attendance)
    if form.is_valid() :
        attendance = form.save(commit=False)
        attendance.published_date = timezone.now()
        attendance.save()
        return redirect('post_list')
else :
    form = PostForm(instance=attendance)
return render(request, 'blog/student_list.html', {'course' : course, 'form' : form})
```

forms.py:

```
class PostForm(forms.ModelForm) :
class Meta :
    model = Attendance
    fields = ('student_name',)

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs) :
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    if self.instance.pk :
        self.fields['student_name'].queryset = Student.objects.filter(course_name=self.instance.course_name)
```

models.py:

```
class Attendance(models.Model) :
course_name = models.ForeignKey(Course, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
student_name = models.ManyToManyField(Student)
instructor_name = models.ForeignKey(Instructor, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
published_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
```

student_list.html:

```
<form method="POST" class="post-form">{% csrf_token %}
       {{ form.as_p }}
       <button type="submit" class="save btn btn-default">Save</button>
       </form>
```

Also, the fields course_name, instructor_name and published_date are saved in the DB. It is only the student_name that is not saved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well this is one of the reasons why using `.save(commit=False)` is indeed not a good idea, because a `ModelForm` will indeed save the `ManyToManyField`. This is done *after* the object itself is saved, since it first needs a primary key.

You can alter the instance wrapped in the form with:

```
def student_list(request, pk):
    course = get_object_or_404(Course, pk=pk)
    teacher = Instructor.objects.get(course_name=course)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = PostForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.instance.course_name = course
            form.instance.instructor_name = teacher
            form.instance.published_date = timezone.now()
            form.save()
        return redirect('post_list')
    else:
        form = PostForm()
    return render(request, 'blog/student_list.html', {'course': course, 'form': form})
```

That being said, if this is the standard behavior, you can just pass the `timezone.now` as default in your model:

```
from django.utils import timezone

class Attendance(models.Model):
    course_name = models.ForeignKey(Course, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    student_name = models.ManyToManyField(Student)
    instructor_name = models.ForeignKey(Instructor, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    published_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True, default=timezone.now)
```

or even better, you can just use [**`auto_now_add=True`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.DateField.auto_now_add):

```
class Attendance(models.Model):
    course_name = models.ForeignKey(Course, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    student_name = models.ManyToManyField(Student)
    instructor_name = models.ForeignKey(Instructor, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    published_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

> **Note**: A `ForeignKey` does *not* store the string representation (or name) of the
>   referenced object in the column, it stores the primary key of the record it
>   references in a column with an  `_id` suffix to a `ForeignKey` field. Therefore
>   `ForeignKey`s usually do *not* end with a `_name` suffix. You might want to
>   consider renaming the <s>`course_name`</s> field to `course`.

> **Note**: A GET request is *not* supposed to have *side-effects*, hence constructing
>   objects when a user makes a GET request, is not compliant with the HTTP
>   standard. Therefore it might be better to remove the creation of the `Attendance`
>   object at the database side.

**EDIT**: You can pass the `course` object to the `PostForm` to filter the queryset. For example:

```
class PostForm(forms.ModelForm) :
    class Meta :
        model = Attendance
        fields = ('student_name',)

    def __init__(self, *args, course=None, **kwargs) :
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if self.instance.pk and not course:
            course = self.instance.course_name
        if course:
            self.fields['student_name'].queryset = Student.objects.filter(course_name=course)
```

Then in the view, you can pass the `Course` object:

```
def student_list(request, pk) :
    course = get_object_or_404(Course, pk=pk)
    teacher = Instructor.objects.get(course_name=course)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = PostForm(request.POST, course=course)
        if form.is_valid() :
            form.instance.course_name = course
            form.instance.instructor_name = teacher
            form.instance.published_date = timezone.now()
            form.save()
        return redirect('post_list')
    else :
        form = PostForm(course=course)
    return render(request, 'blog/student_list.html', {'course' : course, 'form' : form})
```

Comment: Thanks ,it worked, but now in the django form  , all the students are displayed , earlier only the students enrolled for that course used to be displayed which is what we want.

Comment: @ShreyasShetty: then you can use a parameter to the form, see edit.